# Rust cannot return value referencing local variable on HashMap get

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a code looks like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let x = get_hash_map();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn get_hash_map() -> Option<&'static Vec<i32>> {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(1);
    hm.insert("1".to_string(), vec);
    return hm.get("1");
}
```

But I got this error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `hm`
  --> src/main.rs:13:12
   |
13 |     return hm.get("1");
   |            --^^^^^^^^^
   |            |
   |            returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |            `hm` is borrowed here
```

Here is the rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7605176aee2dd3ff77a0cfd04a89db55

Can anyone suggest the alternatives to fix this problem minimally? Thanks!

Comment: Your hashmap is local. It doesn't exist anymore at end of the function. What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fn get_hash_map() -> Option<&'static Vec<i32>> {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(1);
    hm.insert("1".to_string(), vec);
    return hm.get("1");
}
```

This is invalid, because you have declared you are going to return an `Option<&'static Vec<i32>>`, but you are returning an `Option<&'a Vec<i32>>` where `'a` is the current function lifetime. The HashMap will stop existing as soon as the function returns, freeing the vector, and the reference will then become dangling. This is the exact kind of situation the borrow checker is designed to avoid.

Just return the vector by value:

```
fn get_hash_map() -> Option<Vec<i32>> {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(1);
    hm.insert("1".to_string(), vec);
    return hm.remove("1");
}
```

`remove` moves the value out of the map, returning it as an `Option<V>`.

If you then need an `Option<&Vec<i32>>`, you can just use `as_ref()` on your `Option<Vec<i32>>` to get one. Always remember it will become invalid as soon as its value goes out of scope.

Comment: The `remove()` cancels out the role of the `HashMap` as well as the lifetime of references in OP's question. It could be more informative if there's another code block / paragraph touching on that.

Comment: @sebpuetz given that it's not super clear what OP is trying to do, `remove()` was the only reasonable way to achieve what the OP wanted, without completely changing the snippet he posted. I think here references were being used by mistake, and what the OP probably wanted was just to know he had to return things by value.

Answer (score 1):

The `HashMap` `hm` is local to the scope of the `get_hash_map()` function and is dropped as soon as `get_hash_map()` returns. The value returned by `hm.get("1")` contains a reference to this `HashMap`, thus its lifetime is also tied to the scope of `get_hash_map()` which unfortunately is shorter than the ascribed `'static` lifetime.

If you remove the `'static` lifetime and replaced it by some `'a` annotation on the function, you would get a similar error, since again there is no (sound) way to return borrowed data from a function that creates the owner of that data.

You can however create the map in the surrounding scope and pass it via a mutable reference to `get_hash_map`

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    let x = get_hash_map(&mut hm);
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

// note that both `hm` and the reference in the return type have the same 'a lifetime.
fn get_hash_map<'a>(hm: &'a mut HashMap<String, Vec<i32>>) -> Option<&'a Vec<i32>> {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(1);
    hm.insert("1".to_string(), vec);
    hm.get("1");
}
```